# How to deal with an old question with two separate queries

Tags: discussion

The disputed question is this one:
[Any way to use Maximus-two (or similar extension) on Gnome 3.24 in 17.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904738/any-way-to-use-maximus-two-or-similar-extension-on-gnome-3-24-in-17-04)

Notice that in the last paragraph ("*PS: Not really related, but my other issue...*") the asker posed a separate question not directly related to the original query. I posted a comment asking OP to remove the last paragraph and ask a separate question but it seems OP is not active here any more.

Also the other question has already been asked here:
[How do I hide the location indicator in Ubuntu GNOME?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/903381/how-do-i-hide-the-location-indicator-in-ubuntu-gnome)

What should be most advisable thing to do here? Is it fine to just remove the last paragraph? Or better to replace the last paragraph with the link to the other question? Or rather leave the link in the comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the great things about the Stack Exchange model is that it is a collaboratively edited site. So just edit and remove the second question.

If the second question has already been asked and answered, you can leave the OP a comment linking to it, but yes, feel free to edit and remove extra questions if that would improve the post.